# Multiplying lists together

Tags: list, dictionary, python-2.6

Been working on a small class project to make a blackjack game.  I realize that there are a billion how to's on this, but I'm trying to understand coding and build my own...that being said, I've messed up a lot.  This conundrum is confusing to me though...while setting up my deck, I tried this:

```
suits = ['spades', 'hearts', 'clubs', 'diamonds']
ranks = ['ace', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight',     'nine', 'ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']

decks = []

for suit in suits:
    for rank in ranks:
        decks += (rank, suit)
print decks
```

I get the expected outcome of the two lists ordering together:
['ace', 'spades', 'two', 'spades', 'three', 'spades', 'four'...]

However, when I try to combine them into a dictionary as follows:

```
b = dict(zip(decks[1::2], decks[0::2]))
print b
```

I get: {'hearts': 'King', 'clubs': 'King', 'spades': 'King', 'diamonds': 'King'} Why does it only do the King values?

When I tried to rectify with the following code:

```
spade = ['spades']

ranks = ['ace', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']

spades = []

for rank in ranks:
    spades += (rank, spade)
print spades
```

I got this as the output: 
['ace', ['spades'], 'two', ['spades'], 'three', ['spades'],...]

So what gives? Help a noob out!  My intention was to create a deck somewhat elegantly through lists, append values to the cards, create a dictonary and use the values to calculate scores...and trying to understand Python coding better!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comp to create a deck of cards like `[[rank,suits]]`. And `dict()` creates an object from only 2 values `[value1,value2]`. The reason you keep getting `{'hearts': 'King', 'clubs': 'King', 'spades': 'King', 'diamonds': 'King'}` is because a dict has unique `{key:value}` pairs and the last item to be assigned those keys is `King` in the `ranks` array.

```
suits = ['spades', 'hearts', 'clubs', 'diamonds']
ranks = ['ace', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven',
         'eight',     'nine', 'ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']

print [(rank, suit) for suit in suits for rank in ranks]
```

## solution

You can make the keys to the dick the `ranks` and the values an array of the `(rank,suit)` with the same `rank`

```
card_dict = {}
suits = ['spades', 'hearts', 'clubs', 'diamonds']
ranks = ['ace', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven',
         'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
deck = [(rank, suit) for suit in suits for rank in ranks]

map(
    lambda rank: card_dict.update(
        {
            rank: filter(lambda card: rank in card, deck)
        }
    ), ranks
)

print card_dict
```

## result

```
{
  'King': [('King', 'spades'), ('King', 'hearts'), ('King', 'clubs'), ('King', 'diamonds')],
  'seven': [('seven', 'spades'), ('seven', 'hearts'), ('seven', 'clubs'), ('seven', 'diamonds')],
  'Queen': [('Queen', 'spades'), ('Queen', 'hearts'), ('Queen', 'clubs'), ('Queen', 'diamonds')],
  'ace': [('ace', 'spades'), ('ace', 'hearts'), ('ace', 'clubs'), ('ace', 'diamonds')],
  'ten': [('ten', 'spades'), ('ten', 'hearts'), ('ten', 'clubs'), ('ten', 'diamonds')],
  'nine': [('nine', 'spades'), ('nine', 'hearts'), ('nine', 'clubs'), ('nine', 'diamonds')],
  'six': [('six', 'spades'), ('six', 'hearts'), ('six', 'clubs'), ('six', 'diamonds')],
  'two': [('two', 'spades'), ('two', 'hearts'), ('two', 'clubs'), ('two', 'diamonds')],
  'three': [('three', 'spades'), ('three', 'hearts'), ('three', 'clubs'), ('three', 'diamonds')],
  'four': [('four', 'spades'), ('four', 'hearts'), ('four', 'clubs'), ('four', 'diamonds')],
  'five': [('five', 'spades'), ('five', 'hearts'), ('five', 'clubs'), ('five', 'diamonds')],
  'Jack': [('Jack', 'spades'), ('Jack', 'hearts'), ('Jack', 'clubs'), ('Jack', 'diamonds')],
  'eight': [('eight', 'spades'), ('eight', 'hearts'), ('eight', 'clubs'), ('eight', 'diamonds')]
}
```

or if you map by `suits` instead of `ranks`

```
{
  'clubs': [('ace', 'clubs'),
    ('two', 'clubs'),
    ('three', 'clubs'),
    ('four', 'clubs'),
    ('five', 'clubs'),
    ('six', 'clubs'),
    ('seven', 'clubs'),
    ('eight', 'clubs'),
    ('nine', 'clubs'),
    ('ten', 'clubs'),
    ('Jack', 'clubs'),
    ('Queen', 'clubs'),
    ('King', 'clubs')
  ],
  'diamonds': [('ace', 'diamonds'),
    ('two', 'diamonds'),
    ('three', 'diamonds'),
    ('four', 'diamonds'),
    ('five', 'diamonds'),
    ('six', 'diamonds'),
    ('seven', 'diamonds'),
    ('eight', 'diamonds'),
    ('nine', 'diamonds'),
    ('ten', 'diamonds'),
    ('Jack', 'diamonds'),
    ('Queen', 'diamonds'),
    ('King', 'diamonds')
  ],
  'hearts': [('ace', 'hearts'),
    ('two', 'hearts'),
    ('three', 'hearts'),
    ('four', 'hearts'),
    ('five', 'hearts'),
    ('six', 'hearts'),
    ('seven', 'hearts'),
    ('eight', 'hearts'),
    ('nine', 'hearts'),
    ('ten', 'hearts'),
    ('Jack', 'hearts'),
    ('Queen', 'hearts'),
    ('King', 'hearts')
  ],
  'spades': [('ace', 'spades'),
    ('two', 'spades'),
    ('three', 'spades'),
    ('four', 'spades'),
    ('five', 'spades'),
    ('six', 'spades'),
    ('seven', 'spades'),
    ('eight', 'spades'),
    ('nine', 'spades'),
    ('ten', 'spades'),
    ('Jack', 'spades'),
    ('Queen', 'spades'),
    ('King', 'spades')
  ]
}
```

## shuffling

```
import random
random.shuffle(deck)
print deck
```

Comment: Would the mapped structure still like a deck that could be shuffled/randomized?

Comment: @thegreataus no, if you want to constantly change the structure by shuffling leave it as an array `[(rank, suit) for suit in suits for rank in ranks]` if you want to use a `dict` then the only way I can think of is creating a sequence of random numbers for each index and making sure they're unique and then retrieving them from the dict. In other words selecting a random deck instead of sorting.

Comment: Ahhh, ok.  That makes sense.  I was going to try and set a value for the card and use that as a way to determine the player card value...but looks like I will have to take a different approach, muchos gracias senor!

Comment: Could you elaborate on why I would get this as the output for the last bit of my code?  

    ['ace', ['spades'], 'two', ['spades'], 'three', ['spades'],...]

Why is the spades in it's own list within the list?

Comment: Also...how is this line of code:

'deck = [(rank, suit) for suit in suits for rank in ranks]'

different than:

'for suit in suits:
    for rank in ranks:
        decks += (rank, suit)'

Comment: @thegreataus the issue is `spades += (rank,spade)` specifically `+=` as it makes the tuple (rank,spade) a generator and concatenates each value into `spade` one by one so for each iteration of the `for` you actually have this like `spades = spades + [rank] + [['spades']]` since `spade` itself is a list. It would work just fine if you used `.append()` which doesn't treat the tuple `(rank,spade)` as a generator but simply a tuple, but then you would be left with a list like `[(rank,spade),(rank,spade)]`.

Comment: the only difference between `for suit in suits: for rank in ranks: decks += (rank, suit)` and `deck = [(rank, suit) for suit in suits for rank in ranks]` is that the first is a loop that updates some local variable and the second is a construct that iterates a loop returns some value into a list.

Answer (score 2):

Talking about multiplying lists should compel you to use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), and force iteration by converting to `list`

```
import itertools

suits = ['spades', 'hearts', 'clubs', 'diamonds']
ranks = ['ace', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight',     'nine', 'ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']

decks = list(itertools.product(suits,ranks))

print(decks)
```

result

```
[('spades', 'ace'), ('spades', 'two'), ('spades', 'three'), ('spades', 'four'), ('spades', 'five'), ('spades', 'six'), ('spades', 'seven'), ('spades', 'eight'), ('spades', 'nine'), ('spades', 'ten'), ('spades', 'Jack'), ('spades', 'Queen'), ('spades', 'King'), ('hearts', 'ace'), ('hearts', 'two'), ('hearts', 'three'), ('hearts', 'four'), ('hearts', 'five'), ('hearts', 'six'), ('hearts', 'seven'), ('hearts', 'eight'), ('hearts', 'nine'), ('hearts', 'ten'), ('hearts', 'Jack'), ('hearts', 'Queen'), ('hearts', 'King'), ('clubs', 'ace'), ('clubs', 'two'), ('clubs', 'three'), ('clubs', 'four'), ('clubs', 'five'), ('clubs', 'six'), ('clubs', 'seven'), ('clubs', 'eight'), ('clubs', 'nine'), ('clubs', 'ten'), ('clubs', 'Jack'), ('clubs', 'Queen'), ('clubs', 'King'), ('diamonds', 'ace'), ('diamonds', 'two'), ('diamonds', 'three'), ('diamonds', 'four'), ('diamonds', 'five'), ('diamonds', 'six'), ('diamonds', 'seven'), ('diamonds', 'eight'), ('diamonds', 'nine'), ('diamonds', 'ten'), ('diamonds', 'Jack'), ('diamonds', 'Queen'), ('diamonds', 'King')]
```

or since you seem to need a flat list, just flatten it using `chain.from_iterable`:

```
decks = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.product(suits,ranks)))
```

Comment: Ok...so I'm still new to all of this.  What do you mean by a flat list?  With this example, how would you make a non-flat list?  Is there a way to do it without importing...?